# strange characters in facebook post to wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following to post articles to the user's facebook feed. The issue that I have is that the title is being surrounded by characters not included in the post:

{"O":Article Title"}

The php code looks like this:

```
  $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  if (isset($_POST['publish'])){
       $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        try {
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "I found this and wanted to share it", 
                'link'    => $url,
                'picture' => 'http://domain/images/image1.jpg',
                'name'    => $item_title,
                'description'=> $comment
                )
            );
            //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url 
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
```

It is the link item that I am assuming has the problem? I have changed the $url variable from a database record to a fixed string and the problem remains. Any ideas?

Comment: My initial guess is you haven't handled the `item_title` variable properly

Comment: thanks for the reply, item_title is defined (RSS content): `$RSSitem = $RSS_DOC->channel->item[0];
  $item_id  = md5($RSSitem->title);
  $fetch_date = date("Y-m-j G:i:s"); //NOTE: we don't use a DB SQL function so its database independant
  $item_title = $RSSitem->title;` The item_title is not causing any other issues in my code or output. Thanks!